# Find the Sum of digits of M

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Find the sum of all digits in $M$ if,

1. $r=37$
2. For any general $'r'$

$$ M = 9_{(r)} 8_{(r)} 7_{(r)} 6_{(r)} 5_{(r)} 4_{(r)} 3_{(r)} 2_{(r)} 1_{(r)} \times 6_{(r)} $$

Here, $n_{(r)}$ denotes that the digit $n$ appears $r$ times together hence, $M=998877665544332211 \times 66 $ for $r=2$

For example: Consider the number $44526779991$ then sum of its digits is $4+4+5+2+6+7+7+9+9+9+1=63$

Comment: What ave you tried?

Comment: Hint: $987654321 \cdot 6 = 5 \,925 \,925 \,926\,$, $998877665544332211 \cdot 66 = 65 \,925 \,925 \,925 \,925 \,925 \,926\,\,\cdots$

Comment: @MatthewConroy - I tried solving for small values of $r$ and, finding the pattern and applying it to larger values. For example for $r=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ I noted that $M=6_{(r-1)} \underline{592}_{(3r)} 6$ Here, $\underline{xyz}_{(r)}$ denote that the digits $x,y,z$ appear together $r$ times. For example: $M=65925925926$ for $r=1$. I know this is not mathematical approach hence, I need complete solution to it.

Comment: Have you tried to prove that your observed pattern is true?

Comment: @MatthewConroy I want to know how to do it. Somebody told me it can be done using Mathematical Induction but, how, please explain

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You might begin by proving that the $66...6$ number is 
$$
6 \cdot \frac{10^r-1}{9}
$$
and that the $9..98..8.....2..21..1$ number is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^9 i \frac{10^r-1}{9}  10^{(i-1)r}
$$

Then use these forms to prove that the product has the form you claim (by expressing it in a similar form), and hence deduce the sum.

For example, the number 592592592...592 where there are $k$ repetitions of the 592 can be written as
$$
592 \left(\frac{10^{3k}-1}{10^3-1} \right).
$$
In the same way, you can write your product in a closed form and prove that it is equal to the product of the given numbers, and then deduce the sum of the digits.

Comment: I don't think this will help. The OP doesn't want a closed form for the product. He wants a closed form for the sum of digits of the product.

Comment: @NilabroSaha He can use these forms to prove that there are so many 6's, so many 592's, in the final product, and hence deduce the sum.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I get 1998.

Here's how:

$M = 9_{(r)} 8_{(r)} 7_{(r)} 6_{(r)} 5_{(r)} 4_{(r)} 3_{(r)} 2_{(r)} 1_{(r)} \times 6_{(r)}
$

In base $b$,
this is
$M = (b-1)_{(r)} (b-2)_{(r)} ...
2_{(r)} 1_{(r)} \times (m)_{(r)}
$.

Note that
$(m)_{(r)}
= m \times (1)_{(r)}$.

$(1)_{(r)}
=\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} b^j
=\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1}
$,
so
$(a)_{(r)}
=a\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1}
$.

Let
$N
=(b-1)_{(r)} (b-2)_{(r)} ...
2_{(r)} 1_{(r)}
$.

We have
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kx^{k-1}
= \dfrac{1}{(1-x)^2}
$
and
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} kx^{k-1}
=\dfrac{n x^{n + 1} - (n + 1) x^n + 1}{(x - 1)^2}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
N
&=\sum_{k=1}^{b-1} b^{r(k-1)} (k)_{(r)}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{b-1} b^{r(k-1)} k\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1}\\
&=\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1}\sum_{k=1}^{b-1} k(b^r)^{k-1} \\
&=\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1}\dfrac{(b-1) (b^r)^{b} - b (b^r)^{b-1} + 1}{(b^r - 1)^2} 
\quad\text{using } n=b-1, x=b^r\\
&=\dfrac{(b-1) b^{rb} - b^{r(b-1)+1} + 1}{(b-1)(b^r - 1)} \\
\text{so}\\
M
&=N\times (m)_{(r)}\\
&=\dfrac{(b-1) b^{rb} - b^{r(b-1)+1} + 1}{(b-1)(b^r - 1)}m\dfrac{b^r-1}{b-1} \\
&=m\dfrac{(b-1) b^{rb} - b^{r(b-1)+1} + 1}{(b-1)^2} \\
\end{array}
$

If $b=10$,
$N
=\dfrac{9 \times 10^{10r} - 10^{9r+1} + 1}{9(10^r - 1)} 
$
and
$M
=m\dfrac{9\cdot 10^{10r} - 10^{9r+1} + 1}{81}
$.

All the following computations
were done by Wolfy
and reformatted by me.

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{9 \times 10^{10*37} - 10^{9*37+1} + 1}{9(10^{37} - 1)} 
&=9999999999999999999999999999999999999\\ &8888888888888888888888888888888888888\\ &7777777777777777777777777777777777777\\ &6666666666666666666666666666666666666\\ &5555555555555555555555555555555555555\\ &4444444444444444444444444444444444444\\ &3333333333333333333333333333333333333\\ &2222222222222222222222222222222222222\\ &1111111111111111111111111111111111111\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
6\dfrac{9\cdot 10^{10*37} - 10^{9*37+1} + 1}{81}
&=666666666666666666666666666666666666\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&592592592592592592592592592592592592\\
&5925925926\\
\end{array}
$

Get the sum of the digits by

$sumdigits(6\dfrac{9\cdot 10^{10*37} - 10^{9*37+1} + 1}{81})
=1998
$.

The number of occurrences of each digit are

$\begin{array}\\
2s &= 111\\
5s &= 111\\
6s &= 37\\
9s &= 111\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Interesting to note that $111=37\times3$.

Comment: Also 592 = 16 x 37, 925 = 25 x 37, and 259 = 7 x 37.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short program in Java to output $M$ for an input $r$:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;
class Product {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        String p1 = "", q1 = "";
        BigInteger p, q;
        System.out.print("Enter r: ");
        r = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        for(int i = 0; i < r; i++) q1 += '6';
        for(char i = '1'; i <= 9; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j < r; j++) p1 = i + p1;
        p = new BigInteger(p1);
        q = new BigInteger(q1);
        System.out.println( p.multiply(q) );
    }
}
```

And here are all the results to add to @Mathew Conroy's answer:

1. The number of $925$'s in $M$ can be effectively considered to go by multiples of $3$, for our purpose.

$$
r = 1 \rightarrow \text{no. of } 925 \text{'s } = 3 \\
r = 2 \rightarrow 6 \\
r = 3 \rightarrow 9 \\
r = 4 \rightarrow 12 \\
r = 5 \rightarrow 15
$$

2. $M$ can effectively be considered to have $r$ $6$'s appended in front of the $3r$ $925$'s.

$$
r = 1 \rightarrow 6 \\
r = 2 \rightarrow 66 \\
r = 3 \rightarrow 666 \\
r = 4 \rightarrow 6666 \\
r = 5 \rightarrow 66666
$$

The claims are verified till $r = 5$. If the claims turn out true for all $r$, then the sum of digits of $M$ is:

$$
6r + 3r\times (9+2+5) = 54r
$$